# create a view for getting the list of documents where end time is equal or greater than current time and type

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have a requirement to create bit complex queries could you please help me to write.

In my data base I have list of docs, for example:

```
{
  "_id": "26",
  "_rev": "1-53ac67e9ec4b4ce8ffa9cd609e107aaf",
  "customer_name": "Praneeth",
  "type": "trip",
  "duration": "10 hours 27 mins",
  "end_time": "Jan 1, 2014 10:11:00 PM",
  "start_time": "Jan 11, 2014 8:46:00 AM",
}
```

Now I want to create a view which can read current `timestamp` and type from the URL to get the docs whose `end_time` is less than or equal to current `timestamp` and type is `"trip"`. Here type could be anything not only the `trip`, based on `type` being passed from the URL I should get the docs.

Suppose if I write in SQL,  query it would be like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE end_time>="current time passed from the URL as key" and type='type passed from the url as key'
```

My view is like below now how to call this view from the URL to get the desired output

```
    function(doc){
var startTime=new Date(doc.start_time);
var endTime=new Date(doc.end_time);
emit([doc.type,endTime.getTime()], doc);
    }
```

is below one is correct??

```
     http://localhost:5984/trip/_design/current_trip/_view/current_trip?startkey=["trip",1388607960000]&end_key={}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simply emitting in map function of your view `[trip, end_time]`. The CouchDB's rule for order of array keys is to sort it lexicographically. Example data set will be sorted like this:

```
{ end_time: 40, trip: "ABC", ... },
{ end_time: 10, trip: "BCA", ... },
{ end_time: 20, trip: "BCA", ... },
{ end_time: 30, trip: "CAB", ... },
...
```

If you want to have dates up to `end_time` with customer with most recent end_time first, you may consider query parameter `descending=true` as very useful (or emit `[trip, -end_time]` what is even more useful if you need to have different order of fields in key array).

Comment: My view is like below now how to call this view from the URL to get the desired output                                          function(doc){
 var startTime=new Date(doc.start_time);
 var endTime=new Date(doc.end_time);
 emit([doc.type,endTime.getTime()], doc);
}                                                                  is below one is correct??                                                  http://localhost:5984/trip/_design/current_trip/_view/current_trip?startkey=["trip",1388607960000]&end_key={}

Comment: can you please help me to figure it out.

Comment: a bit hard to see in the comment but you still have `startkey` instead of `start_key`. The `end_key` seems to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you...assuming you just want to compare to 'now', you don't need to worry about passing any parameters on the url. Just access the view normally.

```
function(doc) {
    var now = new Date();
    var endTime = new Date(doc.end_time);        
    if(doc.type == \"trip\" &&  endTime > now)
        emit( ... );
}
```